# Tomcat 9 setting external properties

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

This question has been asked many times in Stackoverflow but the solutions provided over there are not working in my case.

We are creating war file using ant script on **JVM - 10**, **win - 64** bit and keeping the file inside webapps folder of **Tomcat-9**. We are trying to load resource bundle from external properties files. For that we have 2 properties file and we are keeping inside C:\Program Files\Ticket App\internalproperties and C:\Program Files\Ticket App\externalproperties folders.

We have tried setting up the classpath inside setclasspath.bat:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Ticket App\internalproperties;C:\Program Files\Ticket App\externalproperties;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
```

It did't work. We also tried keeping the following code inside setenv.bat

```
set CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files\Ticket App\internalproperties;C:\Program Files\Ticket App\externalproperties;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
```

Both the times Tomcat is trying to pick the files from the directory **C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.12-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\bin.**

It will be really helpful if you can please help us on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Place the propertie files in the folder tomcat is looking for them?

Comment: That we can not do. We need to keep the properties file in that specific folder. I am not getting how we can override the path?

Comment: I do not think Tomcat can so easily grab files outside of his "domain of folders" specially in the System drive. maybe someone else knows..

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat 9.0.14 on Linux, it works for me.

In Tomcat's setenv.sh, I have this line
**export CLASSPATH=/opt/abc/conf**

And the below java program works and abc.properties is under /opt/abc/conf

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try{
    input =prop.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc.properties"); 
    prop.load(input);
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("change.monitor.interval"));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The behavior should be same in Windows too.